# JDBC sql request compression

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

In my application I have only one sql request (one SELECT, or one UPDATE, ...). This request may be executed once and goes through a network. Are any ways or techniques to make it optimized or something to run it faster?

Comment: What do you mean??? SELECT statement, DELETE statement, UPDATE statement.

Comment: I mean the whole SQL.  The whole SELECT statement.  This is why someone (not me) gave you a down vote.  Optimization is a statement by statement basis.  Without the SQL statement the question is not specific enough to answer here.  (The way you are asking, it would take a book to explain optimization techniques.)

Comment: Yeah, I know this. But I meant are there any Java techniques (JDBC compatible library or something like this) to shrink the traffic though the network between client and server.

Comment: The question about JDBC compression is valid, this isn't asking for SQL optimisation tips. For example `select * from table` how are you going to optimise that assume all data is required? Network traffic frequently uses binary encoding (e.g. protocol buffers) plus compression ( snapp, bzip etc) so is it possible to enable those in JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with applications using networks.  One, maybe the only important one, is network turns, the other is size of network data.  The first deals with the end to end latency of a round trip of a request and a response, and a client which does not go to the next line of code until it gets an answer from the server.  The other deals with the number of bytes sent and the throughput.

The big issue is network turns.  It takes about as long to send a 30 byte packet as it does to send a 1400 byte packet.  A lot of the time there is an exchange of a lot of small (80 to 300 byte) packets.

So the technique is to reduce the number of network turns.  Use the asynchronous api if there is one and you can.  Try to combine queries into one complex query instead of lots of simple queries.  Especially avoid doing a loop and doing a query in the loop, if you can combine the result in one query.

Also, use indexes on your table, and make sure that your query has an appropriate index to use.

Comment: "use indexes on your table" - What index? Do you mean primary key? And what is an appropriate index? Thx.

Comment: All good advice, but what if the datasize is large? Then the size of data, especially if uncompressed, can be a major factor in the time taken to retrieve data. The question asks about JDBC so a fair assumption is the OP is not writing a JDBC driver and doesn't have access to low level APIs to control packet size or otherwise reduce network turns. Loops in SQL are bad and appropriate indexes good sure, but the question mentions 'compression' which is a valid thought. Probably the JDBC driver itself implements that if used.

Comment: If the data in the result set is large and you need all the data, there is nothing you can do to make it take less time.  The time it takes to go over the network will be how long it takes.  Unless you can reduce the number of fields or the number of records in the result set.

Comment: Not that this answer isn't interesting, but it has literally _nothing_ about compression, which is what the question was about

Comment: @cornuz I did realize that when I wrote the answer.  My answer is how to make the result set smaller for less network traffic.  Since the data is passed over the network between the database client and server using the vendor's code if the database vendor id not implement compression there is nothing you can do.  The reason db vendors do not implement compression is hard to explain.